# Exportar una consulta SQL a un archivo TXT

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql

buenos días, estoy teniendo inconvenientes a la hora de exportar los resultados de una consulta de `SQL` a un archivo de **TXT**, el problema por el cual no puedo exportarla es porque genera errores por los casteos que hay dentro de la consulta.

Esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT CAST(TSMS_exportar AS NVARCHAR(100)) + '/' + 
        CLI_apenom + '/' +  
        CAST(SOL_titulo AS NVARCHAR(100)) + '/' + 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CAST(PLAN_cuota AS MONEY), 1), ',', '|' ), '.', ', '), '|','.' ) + '/' + 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CAST(PLAN_nominal AS MONEY), 1), ',', '|' ), '.', ',' ), '|' ,'.' ) 
FROM Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle 
    INNER JOIN Mensaje_Electronico_Encabezado 
        ON Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle.MEE_id = Mensaje_Electronico_Encabezado.MEE_Id 
    INNER JOIN Solicitud 
        ON Mensaje_Electronico_Encabezado.SOL_titulo = Solicitud.ANTITSOL 
    INNER JOIN TempSMS 
        ON TempSMS.MED_id = Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle.MED_id 
WHERE Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle .PLAN_cuota IS NOT NULL 
    AND Solicitud.ANIDCOB IN ('00010', '00086' ,'00093', '00097') 
    AND TSMS_exportar IS NOT NULL 
    AND PER_id IN ((SELECT MAX(IdPeriodo) FROM Periodos WHERE IdProcesoAdmin = 6)) 
    AND PROCESOADMIN_id = 6
```

Y para exportar el resultado hago lo siguiente:

```
SET @comando ='bcp "toda la consulta anterior" queryout ' etc
```

El problema radica a la hora de usar esto: `'/'` y los signos dentro del `REPLACE`

¿Cómo se hace de manera correcta?  UN dato a aclarar, es que la consulta dentro del bcp no está escalonada como muestro al principio, está toda en una sola fila.

Comment: Si tu problema como dices pasa por un tema de "casteo" de los datos, te sugiero: (1) quita de tu pregunta todo lo que tiene que ver con el bcp por que es ruido (2) agrega el mensaje de error que te está dando la consulta (3) agrega una muestra de los datos que están dando el error. Sin (2) y (3) lamentablemente es casi imposible poder ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: Si mi problema fuera de casteo, pondría eso. Por lo que,1 como dije el problema está en la forma que está escrita la consulta dentro del 'bcp "consulta" ya que ahí dentro es donde los |  ' , generar error de sintaxis. 2 No hay error generado en la consulta, es error de sintaxis. @PatricioMoracho

Comment: Ok, me confundió seguramente lo de "es porque genera errores por los casteos que hay dentro de la consulta."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mejor sería que conviertas la consulta en una vista o procedimiento almacenado para que la instrucción bcp quede de la forma más sencilla posible debido a las limitaciones que tiene la instrucción.

```
CREATE VIEW vwConultaExportar
AS
SELECT TSMS_exportar, 
        CLI_apenom,
        SOL_titulo,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CAST(PLAN_cuota AS MONEY), 1), ',', '|' ), '.', ', '), '|','.' ) PLAN_cuota,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CAST(PLAN_nominal AS MONEY), 1), ',', '|' ), '.', ',' ), '|' ,'.' ) PLAN_nominal
FROM Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle 
    INNER JOIN Mensaje_Electronico_Encabezado 
        ON Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle.MEE_id = Mensaje_Electronico_Encabezado.MEE_Id 
    INNER JOIN Solicitud 
        ON Mensaje_Electronico_Encabezado.SOL_titulo = Solicitud.ANTITSOL 
    INNER JOIN TempSMS 
        ON TempSMS.MED_id = Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle.MED_id 
WHERE Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle .PLAN_cuota IS NOT NULL 
    AND Solicitud.ANIDCOB IN ('00010', '00086' ,'00093', '00097') 
    AND TSMS_exportar IS NOT NULL 
    AND PER_id IN ((SELECT MAX(IdPeriodo) FROM Periodos WHERE IdProcesoAdmin = 6)) 
    AND PROCESOADMIN_id = 6;
```

Pero lo ideal es que además uses el argumento para indicar el separador de columnas en vez de incluirlo en tu consulta.

```
SET @comando ='bcp "SELECT * FROM vwConultaExportar" queryout -t/'
```

Puedes ver más opciones para terminadores de fila y columna [aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Pensé en esa solución, obviamente es posible implementarla. Solo quería saber si mi select se podía modificar de alguna forma para evitar el error de sintaxis que meciono. Gracias!

Comment: Se puede modificar, pero no es lo ideal. Lo mejor es mantener código que sea fácil de mantener y modificar.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración :)